# C/C++ application dependency libraries

Tags: c++, linker

I am programming applictions written in C/C++, in my project I am using SMFL library for my GUI.The way I use SMFL is that I built it from the source,and link the compiled library.So the procedure can be summarized below:

1. install the libraries dependent by SMFL, that is "**pthread opengl xlib udev xrandr xcursor freetype openal flac vorbis**";
2. build the SMFL source and get the final library files;
3. build my project using the SMFL library file;
4. So the application I built could be distributed to others.

Then a question arises, do other users who get my built application have to install the libraries used by SFML(i.e. pthread opengl xlib udev xrandr xcursor freetype openal flac vorbis)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all dependent libraries must be installed. Referencing udev and xlib indicates that you're most likely referring to Linux.

If you build and deploy your application using a Linux distribution's native package manager, like rpm for Fedora-based distributions, and apt for Debian-based distributions, then installing your rpm or deb package will result in all dependent packages getting automatically installed as well, making this process a moot point.

A quick check shows that SFML is a popular library that's already available in most mainstream Linux distributions. There is no apparent reason to build it yourself. Just use the one that already comes with your Linux distribution, and save yourself all those headaches.

There are some edge cases that call for building a custom or a different version of a library that's already included in the distribution. In that case that library can also get build with rpmbuild or debuild. The only additional twist here is that additional, advanced techniques must be used to make it possible to seamlessly have the custom-built library installed alongside the one that comes with the Linux distribution.

But, taking advantage of your Linux distribution's native package management tools is the easiest way to handle these kinds of common dependencies.